# Find a sigma algebra

Tags: probability

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$ be equipped with Lebesgue measure $P$ and Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra . Consider two function on $\Omega$ : $X(\omega)=\omega^2$ and $Y(\omega)=1_{(1/3,2/3)} (\omega) $.
I have to find the $\sigma $-algebras: $\sigma(X),\sigma(Y)\text{ and }\sigma(XY)$.

I know $\sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(B): B\in{B(R)}\} $

$X^{-1}(a,b):$
 $[0,1] \quad  \mbox{if} \quad a<0,b>1;\\
{ [0,\sqrt{b}] \quad if \quad a<0,0<b \le{1}}\\
{ [\sqrt{a},1] \quad if \quad 0<a<1,b>1}\\
{ [\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}] \quad if \quad 0<a<b \le{1}}\\
{\emptyset \quad \mbox{in the other case}}$

so $\sigma(X)=B([0,1])$or $B(R) \cap \Omega$ ?

Comment: Are you assuming $\omega$ is a random variable uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$?  Only after $\omega$ is defined does it make sense to define $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$ as random variables.  Is your problem is to find the sigma algebras associated with the density functions of the marginal and joint distributions?

Comment: The text of the the exercise is that up.

Comment: While you may have copied accurately the exercise found in your textbook, bear in mind that exercises at the end of a book chapter or section are understood by the Reader in their context.  When you ask a Question, you must supply context.  In any case the one part of the exercise that seems unsolved at this point is $\sigma(XY)$, which I read to be the sigma algebra generated by the set of values of $XY$.  What are your thoughts about this last part of the exercise?

Comment: $\sigma(XY)=\{[0,1/3) \cup (2/3,1],B([1/3,2/3])$

Answer (score 2):

$Y(\omega)$ should be easy, right? It only takes on two values, $0,1$, so you just need to consider cases when $0\in B$, $1\in B$. On the other hand $X(\omega)$ will have a sigma algebra that is generated by all open intervals (it is a continuous function afterall). This will be equivalent to the standard Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: @GiulyB: for their product, you can look at subcases when $x\in (1/3,2/3)$ and otherwise. inside and outside this interval, the functions are again continuous.

Comment: @GiulyB: $\sigma(X)$ is *generated* by $X^{-1}((a,b))$, it's not equal.